# Installing Service Pack 1 for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I have Windows 7 on my laptop computer. Windows Update is configured to download and install updates automatically. I don't see any Windows Service Pack installed.

[image]

Do I have to install this Service Pack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Do not have SP1 installed. And you do not *have to* install SP1. But you can, if you want to. Follow the [instructions here](http://windows.microsoft.com/installwindows7sp1) to install it.

If you have SP1 installed, it'll look like this -

[image]